# Python 3, looping through a .txt file, with values from another .txt file, then creating variables that match

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have **2 Files**, Names.txt and Paragraph.txt

**Names.txt**

> *John Anna Ron David*

**Paragraph.txt**

> *David, who has been embodying Larry David for years on Curb Your Enthusiasm, which could technically come back for another season. Then, one by one, John Barrasso,  John McCain, John Thune, Orrin Hatch, and Jeff Flake changed their votes to yes.*

The goal is to loop through the Paragraph.txt file, with Names.txt values, and create a variable for each name, that is found in Names.txt

4 Variables have to be created, Integers, and the value of each variable, has to be the number of times the name popped up in Paragraph.txt.

*Example; there has to be a variable called David which is equal to 2, since the name David appeared 2 times in Paragraph.txt*

How can I achieve this, using for loops?

Any suggestions is welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is relatively easy to do with Python's re (Regular Expressions) library.

```
import re

output = {}
with open('Names.txt', 'r') as names_file:
    with open('Paragraph.txt', 'r') as paragraph_file:
        names = names_file.read().split(' ')
        paragraph = paragraph_file.read()
        for name in names:
            output[name] = len(re.findall(name, paragraph))

print(output)
```

Comment: That was quick! Thank you, appreciate it!